# Easier way to search for a specific x-value in a vector of QPointF

Tags: c++, qt, search

i have an array of QVectors containing QPointFs with time(x)/temperature(y)-values which will be used in a plot later. One of them is OWMTemp. If i search a temperature(y) at a specified time(x) i do the following which works.

```
QVector<QPointF> pt[20];

for(int i=0;i<pt[OWMTemp].size();i++)
{
    if(pt[OWMTemp].at(i).x() == Hour)
    {
        temp = pt[OWMTemp].at(i).y();
        break;
    }
}
```

I couldn't find a Qt function to do this any better.
Does anyone know a easier way to do this?

Thanks,
Ralf.

Comment: Maybe using the STL: `auto iter = std::find_if(pt[OWMTemp].begin(), pt[OWMTemp].end(), [Hour](const QPointF& measure) { return abs(measure.x() - Hour) < 1e-8; });`
It is shorter and may be a little bit faster (and I added a tolerance for the comparison). To be even faster than that, though, if points are sorted by `x` (ascending or descending), consider a [dichotomic search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search). But in that case, I would not call it an easier way.

Comment: Other than that, if consecutive points all have the same gap on their `x` values, consider using the first 2 points to calculate the gap, then go directly to what you calculate will be the data point you are looking for. This requires an even stronger precondition than above but should do the job in O(1) complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Atmo, if i use std::find_if instead of my code above in Qt5.15.2 i get a address (e.g. 0xba1400) as return iter, not a integer like value between 0 and 47 as expected. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: @Atmo I would suggest using `constBegin()` and `constEnd()` to prevent unwanted  detachment (and a copy of the data) of `QVector` in case it has more than 1 shared reference.

Comment: Using `==` when either of operands is a floating point number is a kind of time bomb. Sooner or later it will make a very big and surprising boom! Just do not do it unless you are more than 100 percent sure you know your data really well. In other cases you should convert it to integral types before the comparison or use something like `qFuzzyCompare`.

Comment: Important piece of info is missing: are your data sorted by `x`?

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager Too late too change my comment but that is a good point.

Comment: @SalemSabrehagen `std::find_if` returns an iterator, hence the name of the variable in my sample (documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)). If you take `constBegin()`/`constEnd()` instead of `begin()`/`end()`, that means you have to do `if (iter != pt[OWMTemp].constEnd())` to check if a point was found (if no point is found, do nothing), the point will be `(*iter)` and the temperature will be `(*iter).y()`, or more concisely `iter->y()`.